# Print smart pointer vector using a template function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, smart-pointers

I wrote a function to print a given `vector`.

```
template <typename T>
void print_vector(std::string text, std::vector<T> &vect){
    std::cout << ">>>>>>>>>> " << text << " <<<<<<<<<<" << std::endl;
    for(T &t: vect){
        std::cout << t << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "--------------------" << std::endl;
}
```

But when I give a `vector` of `shared_ptr` to the function, it prints the address, but not the pointed value.

Is there a way to print the value when the element is a `shared_ptr`..? 
I tried the following way, but it gives me a compile error and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void print_vector(std::string text, std::vector<T> &vect){
    std::cout << ">>>>>>>>>> " << text << " <<<<<<<<<<" << std::endl;
    for(T &t: vect){
        if(std::is_same<T, std::shared_ptr<F>>::value) {
            std::cout << *t << ", ";
        } else {
            std::cout << t << ", ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "--------------------" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overload your function for vectors of smart pointers.

```
template <typename T>
void print_vector(std::string text, std::vector<T> &vect){
    std::cout << ">>>>>>>>>> " << text << " <<<<<<<<<<" << std::endl;
    for(T &t: vect){
        std::cout << t << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "--------------------" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print_vector(std::string text, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> &vect){
    std::cout << ">>>>>>>>>> " << text << " <<<<<<<<<<" << std::endl;
    for(auto &t: vect){
        std::cout << *t << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "--------------------" << std::endl;
}
```

If you have more cases where you wish to print something different, you may find that some of the overloads are ambiguous, you may have to disable the ambiguous templates when they should match each other.

Comment: Why do you need to involve `enable_if` at all? Partial ordering will pick the second one if you have a `vector<shared_ptr<T>>`.

Comment: @Praetorian Good point. There are situations where it is needed to disambiguate, which is worth pointing out

Answer (score 2):

You can overload operator for `shared_ptr` check out the following code:

```
template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const shared_ptr<T>& s_ptr)
{
    if (s_ptr != nullptr)
        out << (*s_ptr);
    return out;
}

template <typename T>
void print_vector(std::string text, std::vector<T> &vect){
    std::cout << ">>>>>>>>>> " << text << " <<<<<<<<<<" << std::endl;
    for(T &t: vect){
        std::cout << t << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "--------------------" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to overload the stream operator for shared_ptr, this could either be for a specific type or for all types:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::shared_ptr< T >& p)
{
  if ( p )
  {
    os << *p;
  }
  else
  {
    os << "<null>";
  }
  return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just overload the function template:

```
template <typename T>
void print_vector(std::string text, std::vector<T> &vect){
    std::cout << ">>>>>>>>>> " << text << " <<<<<<<<<<" << std::endl;
    for(T &t: vect){
        std::cout << t << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "--------------------" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print_vector(std::string text, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> &vect) {
    std::cout << ">>>>>>>>>> " << text << " <<<<<<<<<<" << std::endl;
    for(auto &t: vect){
        std::cout << *t << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "--------------------" << std::endl;
}
```

Now it will handle both cases.